# how to make an Android phone locked down fully?

Tags: android

I have seen this feature on McAfee WaveSecure.  Is there a sample application demonstrates how to lock-down a mobile with a custom screen?

I have seen few with Admin APIs, I am just looking for a sample application  with a custom screen

Thanks

Comment: Are you planning to use system lock?

Comment: Yes, with a custom screen it seems lot difficult task

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Toddler Lock (FAQ: http://www.toddlerlock.com/3.html ) is one of the few apps that has managed to achieve this, the source code is not publically available though.

There are some hints in these questions:

[Android - Is It possible to disable the click of home button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162182/android-is-it-possible-to-disable-the-click-of-home-button/)

[How to shield the home key if my app is active? (Screensaver, Lockscreen)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633260/how-to-shield-the-home-key-if-my-app-is-active-screensaver-lockscreen)

[How to lock android buttons/phone from code (screen lock)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953689/how-to-lock-android-buttons-phone-from-code-screen-lock)

The general idea is that while you cannot completely override the Home key (as you can do with the Back key and similar), you can set your application up as the receiver for the broadcast that is sent out from the key.